# relative path to .Exe

Tags: batch-file, path

I need to create a Batch file which has a relative path to a C# application executable. When I run the batch file the program needs to start regardless on which PC it is. 
Any help will be appreciated.
Kind regards

Comment: Are you asking how to reference the batch script from the C# application? Is the batch script on one machine and you want other machines to run it from there?

Comment: The folder in which the C# application is needs to be copy/pasted from my machine to another machine. I need to create a batch file which points to the executable of that C# application. The path that has to be defined needs to be relative. I need to reference the exe from the batch file.

Comment: I am assuming that the cmd script does not know where the C# executable is located. Is that correct? If so, you should look into the `%~$PATH:I` variable using `FOR /?`. I do not know what you mean by "has to be relative".

Comment: my task is to create a batch file. This file needs to be created in such a way that when the C# application folder is copy/paste from 1 PC to another , the batch file will still run the application. The batch file need to point to the executable, but the path needs to be relative so it runs on any PC. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this. On your local machine, create this file. You need to know the machine name where the program currently resides and provide it as the first parameter. If the sharename could be different from C$, then it needs to be part of the parameter or another parameter.

=== runit.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET EXITCODE=0
PUSHD \\%1\C$\theprogdir
DIR

REM Replace this with starting the C# program
CALL thisistheprog.bat

SET EXITCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%
POPD
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```